# Does switching what gets assigned to the key and what gets assigned to the value, make a difference in a KeyValuePair collection?

Tags: c#

I've reviewing some code which involves the use of a [KeyValuePair collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-5.0). However, the code switches the key for the value, and the value for the key. e.g.:

```cs
KeyValuePair<vwDataDictionary, string> kvp = 
    new KeyValuePair<vwDataDictionary, string>(item, col_name);
```

The `vwDataDictionary` is a SQL View which returns all the data from the SQL Server system view INFORMATION_SCHEMA, plus some additional fields.

I'm wondering if this will have any odd side effects. For example, I would think it would be hard to produce all the fields required in an INFORMATION_SCHEMA record, just to match the value which is the name of a column in a table. But maybe I'm wrong. Does it matter how someone puts the data into a KeyValuePair collection?

Comment: It seems very odd to have a dictionary as a key. The key should be something that you want to look up a value for. I would suspect you want the column name as a key and then information about the column as a value. But maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're doing.

Comment: Also you don't show any code that *"switches the key for the value and the value for the key"*. It's not clear what the question is to me.

Comment: Define "KeyValuePair collection". Usually this struct is used by something like `Dictionary<,>`, which can have issues if the key type doesn't implement equality methods (Equals and GetHashCode). On the other hand, if you just have an array or list of KeyValuePairs (as glorified Tuples) that might be just fine.

Comment: why not to use calculated hash of that key(dictionary) instead of using an actual object?

Comment: The code you are reviewing is, in a word, bizarre. Future developers maintaining this code will probably say, "WTF?" Unless there is a compelling reason to do this, I would send the review back for rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not much.

- If you do a lookup with a larger object, it will take longer.
- Using objets as keys makes the dictionary larger, and is not recommended.

If `vwDataDictionary` is the object you have at the time to do the lookup with. I would suggest you instead use the HashCode, as all objects have the `GetHashCode()` of the object as the key.

Comment: This is not correct. The dictionary size will not change when reversing the key and value. Dictionaries use GetHashCode already, and hash codes by themselves are not unique, so they are not safe to use as a replacement for an actual lookup key.